# Run QThreads on different cores

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

Using `Mac OS 10.9` `QT 5.1` and `C++` on a `8 cores` MBP

I made a little program which run 8 different QThread. The execution seems to be linear and not parallel as it should : the 1st thread starts with `run()`, and the 2nd one starts only when the first finished the `run()` routine...

On the activity monitor I should see a value higher than 100% for the cpu usage if the QThread was executing in the same time but it never happens.

Does someone know how to run QThread on **different** cores?

## main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include "MyThread.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyThread t0 (0);
    MyThread t1 (1);
    MyThread t2 (2);

    t0.run();
    t1.run();
    t2.run();


    return 0;
}
```

## MyThread.h

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>

class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(int threadNumber, QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();

private:
    int _threadNumber;

};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

## MyThread.cpp

```
#include <QDebug>
#include "MyThread.h"


MyThread::MyThread(int threadNumber, QObject *parent)
{
    _threadNumber = threadNumber;
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    qDebug() << "Hi, I'm" << _threadNumber  << "named" << currentThreadId() << "and I start";
    // Some long task
    qDebug() << "Hi, I'm" << _threadNumber <<"and I'm done";

}
```

Comment: Can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you're right!

Comment: You really should read the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-starting.html). Multithreading will cause a lot of pain otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code from invoking `.run()` to

```
t0.start();
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

The idea is QThread's `start()` method does the necessary to setup the thread, and then it invokes your overridden `run()` on the thread.  If you just invoke `run()` directly yourself, nothing actually creates the thread for you and you'd expect to see exactly the serial execution you're seeing.